# Get random value from nested child class

Tags: c#

I have a object like below in my program:

```
var allNode = new NodeClass()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Node = new NodeClass()
            {
                Id = 2,
                Node = new NodeClass()
                {
                    Id = 3,
                    Node = new NodeClass()
                    {
                        Id = 4,
                        Node = new NodeClass()
                        {
                            Id = 5,
                            Node =  new NodeClass()
                            {
                                Id = 6
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

Now i want to get a random child object and get access to `Id` value.
What i came up with is this:

```
        var listOfNodes = new List<NodeClass>()
        {
            allNode,
        };

        var lastNode = allNode;

        while (true)
        {
            lastNode = lastNode.Node;
            if (lastNode != null)
            {
                listOfNodes.Add(lastNode);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Random Node: ");
        Console.WriteLine(listOfNodes.OrderBy(x=> Guid.NewGuid()).First().Id);
```

I want to know is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Unless you keep a counter of how many linked child nodes one node has, I see no better way of achieving this. However you are unnecessarily ordering with Linq. A Random.NextInt on the list would suffice if you only need one node.

Comment: However you could iterate through all nodes and do a random check on each one if you want to 'randomly select the current one'. I'm not sure how solid that solution would work.

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of Random class somewhere. Note that it's pretty important not to create a new instance each time you need a random number. You should reuse the old instance to achieve uniformity in the generated numbers. You can have a static field somewhere (be careful about thread safety issues

```
static Random rnd = new Random();
```

Ask the Random instance to give you a random number with the maximum of the number of items in the ArrayList

```
int r = rnd.Next(list.Count);
```

Display the string

```
MessageBox.Show((string)list[r]);
```